# Condition for module to not be free

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be a module over a ring $R$ with $1$.  Suppose that $rm=0$ for some nonzero $r \in R$ and $m \in M$.  Can we conclude $M$ is not free?

Here is my attempt.  Suppose $M$ is free with basis $m_1,\cdots m_N$. Write $m=c_1m_1+\cdots+c_Nm_N$.  Then $rc_1m_1+\cdots rc_Nm_N=0$. Now, if some $rc_i \neq 0$, then we are done since we've shown that $\{m_i\}$ is in fact not a basis.

How do we proceed?

Comment: Well, depending a little bit on your definition of "free," a ring $R$ with zero-divisors is probably a free module over itself, yes?

Comment: Ok, so this condition is not sufficient to prove that $R$ is not free.  In general is there an easy way to show a module is not free, simply by finding some sort of relation?

Comment: More specifically, I am looking at $R_1\oplus\{0\}$ as a module over $R_1\oplus R_2$, and I want to show it is not free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have learned the condition $\operatorname{Ann}_R(m)\ne0$ for all $m\in M$ is not enough to conclude that $M$ is not a free module. (Simple counterexamples are given by $M=R$, and $R$ a ring with zero divisors, e.g. $R=\mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z$.)

> If you assume $\operatorname{Ann}_R(M)\ne0$, then the module can't be free (unless it is $0$).

In the particular example you mentioned in the comments, $R=R_1\times R_2$, and $M=R_1\times\{0\}$ we have $\operatorname{Ann}_R(M)=\{0\}\times R_2\ne0$.